# Toggle show/hide element where default on refresh is hide

Tags: javascript, html

My script successfully shows and hides a column in the table, I would like by default for it to be hidden and the script to reveal it.

Thanks for your help.

```
<a onclick="myFunction()" style="float:right;">Hide/Show</a>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>TO Date</th>
    <th id="myDIV">LDG Date</th>
    <th>TO Time</th>
    <th>LDG Time</th>
    <th>Dep. air.</th>
    <th>Arr. air.</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
{% for l in logbook %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ l.TO_Date }}</td>
    <td id="myDIV">{{ l.LDG_Date }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.TO_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.LDG_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.dep_airport }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.arr_airport }}</td>
    <td ><a style="color:red;" href="{{ url_for('logbookdelete',id_del=l.id ) }}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document. Use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, I have tried to change to a class, getElementsByClassName, but it still isn't working, would you be able to provide an example using my html in my question. many thanks

Comment: There's no initial style in the involving elements, hence `x.style.display` will never be `block` at refresh. Even if you'd add the style to the elements, the logic wouldn't work. Hide the elements using CSS style sheet, and toggle the class hiding elements with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add *style="display: none;"* to your cells:

```
<th class="myDIV" style="display: none;">
```

**Notice I've changed id to class as you are not supposed to have two equal id's on the same page.**

But I'd do that this way:

```
<style>
  .ldg-date-hidden .myDIV { display: none; }
</style>

<a onclick="myFunction()" style="float:right;">Hide/Show</a>

<table id="myTable" class="ldg-date-hidden">
<tr>
    <th>TO Date</th>
    <th class="myDIV">LDG Date</th>
    <th>TO Time</th>
    <th>LDG Time</th>
    <th>Dep. air.</th>
    <th>Arr. air.</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
{% for l in logbook %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ l.TO_Date }}</td>
    <td class="myDIV">{{ l.LDG_Date }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.TO_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.LDG_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.dep_airport }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.arr_airport }}</td>
    <td ><a style="color:red;" href="{{ url_for('logbookdelete',id_del=l.id ) }}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").classList.toggle("ldg-date-hidden");  
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sadly not working for me. I have 1) added <style>.ldg-date-hidden .myDiv { display: n..... 2) changed <table id="myTable" class="ldg-date-hidden"> 3) added all the class="myDIV" to the th and td 4) changed the <script>..at the bottom

Comment: @ob318 sorry, I missed it - there is .myDiv in the CSS and in the td/th there is myDIV - try to make them equal letter case.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the initial state by putting the inline style (display:none) on the tag, its not the best way but that should work.

I recommend you to make the styles on a css file separated of the html file to avoid hierarchy issues.

```
const x = document.getElementById('myDIV');

function toggleVisibility() {
  if (x.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    x.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    x.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

CSS file

```
.hidden: { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fer, I have tried to change this and also to a class, but it still isn't working, would you be able to provide an example using my html in my question. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the column by setting display:none by default and then you can do the below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
      if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
        x[i].style.display = "block";
      } else { 
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: the solution by @beamer is far better than this